# Office 365 Rest Data Extensions: Find by Property Value

Tags: office365, office365-restapi

When saving an object with an extension, how can I find objects by filtering on the value of an extension property?

To clarify by sticking with the contoso example:

I have saved an object with the following extension:

```
...
  "Extensions": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfc984d-b826-40d7-b48b-57002df800e5@1717f226-49d1-4d0c-9d74-709fad664b77')/Messages
('AAMkAGEbs88AAB84uLuAAA=')/extensions('Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Com.Contoso.Referral')",
      "Id": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Com.Contoso.Referral",
      "ExtensionName": "Com.Contoso.Referral",
      "CompanyName": "Wingtip Toys",
      "ExpirationDate": "2015-12-30T11:00:00.000Z",
      "DealValue": 10000,
      "TopModels@odata.type": "#Collection(Int32)",
      "TopModels": [
        3001,
        4002,
        5003
      ],
    }
...
```

How would I query all objects which a have a DealValue of 10000?

The examples given in the docs just query by extension name:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/Id%20eq%20'Com.Contoso.Referral')&$expand=Extensions($filter=Id%20eq%20'Com.Contoso.Referral')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. It is only possible to query by the id.